# How does Smarty work when I define my Cache Function Handler?

Tags: php, function, caching, smarty, handler

I am trying to use my [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) [Cache Handler Function](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/section.template.cache.handler.func.php). At the beginning, I use the same example function that is posted in the [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) manual.

```
function mysql_cache_handler($action, &$smarty_obj, &$cache_content, 
              $tpl_file=null, $cache_id=null, $compile_id=null, $exp_time=null);
```

The problem is that, when I try to do

```
$smarty->display("template.tpl", $cache_id);
```

variable `$cache_content` is always empty … Can someone explain why?

**Update:** yes i do, and i also set $smarty->caching = true;

Comment: Grammar: "how works smarty" -> "how does smarty work".  (And if I knew the answer, I'd give it.  What's smarty?  Some kind of a PHP caching framework?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you do

```
$smarty->cache_handler_func = 'mysql_cache_handler';
```

before the display()?